# Frequent time outs with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I've been noticing that I get timeouts when using pacman. Often.

```
mike@longshot:~☺  sudo pacman -Syu
[sudo] password for root: 
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.cedia.org.ec : Resolving timed out after 10520 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from download.nus.edu.sg : Resolving timed out after 10519 milliseconds
^C
Interrupt signal received

mike@longshot:~☺  sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
```

I've tried `rankmirrors`, and [reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reflector), as well as the [mirrorlist generator](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/).

I can get faster downloads, but I still get frequent timeouts.

```
mike@longshot:~☺  sudo pacman -S bluez bluez-utils
warning: bluez-5.40-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (2) bluez-5.40-1  bluez-utils-5.40-1

Total Download Size:   0.93 MiB
Total Installed Size:  8.00 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      6.30 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'bluez-utils-5.40-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.localmsp.org : Resolving timed out after 10518 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'bluez-utils-5.40-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from lug.mtu.edu : Resolving timed out after 10520 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'bluez-utils-5.40-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from muug.ca : Resolving timed out after 10520 milliseconds
```

This is a low level annoyance I would love to make go away, and one that I don't see when making other http requests.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a different `XferCommand` in your conf?

Comment: The only two lines with XferCommand in /etc/pacman.conf are commented out:
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - -f %u > %o
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u

Comment: That is the default. You could run pacman in debug mode to see if it generates more interesting error messaging about the network...